# [React-Native][Jest]SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

Tags: javascript, testing, react-native, jestjs

It seems babel transform works in my testcase code, but es6 syntax in `node_modules` does not.

### Error

[image: img]

### environment

> npm 4.5
>
> MacOS Sierra

### jest config

```
{
  "preset": "react-native",
  "globals": {
    "__DEV__": true
  },
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest"
  }
}
```

### babelrc

```
{
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "presets": ["react-native"],
      "plugins": [["import", { "libraryName": "antd-mobile" }]]
    },
    "development": {
      "presets": ["react-native"],
      "plugins": [["import", { "libraryName": "antd-mobile" }]]
    },
    "production": {
    }
  }
}
```

### testcase

```
import 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import Index from '../index.ios.js';

it('renders correctly', () => {
  const tree = renderer.create(
    <Index />
  );
});
```

### package.json

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "web": "roadhog server",
    "build-web": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production roadhog build",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "ios": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node themes/theme.rn.config.js && react-native run-ios",
    "android": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node theme/theme.rn.config.js && react-native run-android",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js src test",
    "precommit": "npm run lint",
    "test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test jest --config .jest.config.json --no-cache"
  },
  "engines": {
    "install-node": "6.9.2"
  },
  "theme": "./themes/theme.web.config.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "antd-mobile": "^1.0.8",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.9.2",
    "dva": "^1.2.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "rc-form": "^1.3.0",
    "react": "15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "15.4.2",
    "react-native": "0.42.3",
    "react-native-chart": "^1.0.8-beta",
    "react-native-gesture-password": "^0.2.0",
    "react-native-scrollable-tab-view": "^0.7.4",
    "react-native-smart-gesture-password": "^2.1.0",
    "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.7",
    "recharts": "^0.21.2",
    "socket.io-client": "^1.7.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-jest": "^19.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-dva-hmr": "^0.3.2",
    "babel-plugin-import": "^1.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "^1.9.1",
    "cross-env": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint": "^3.12.2",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^13.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^2.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^6.8.0",
    "expect": "^1.20.2",
    "husky": "^0.13.3",
    "jest": "^19.0.2",
    "less-vars-to-js": "^1.1.2",
    "postcss-pxtorem": "^4.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "15.4.2",
    "redbox-react": "^1.3.2",
    "roadhog": "^0.6.0-beta1"
  }
}
```

### debug message

```
jest version = 19.0.2
test framework = jasmine2
config = {
  "automock": false,
  "bail": false,
  "browser": false,
  "cacheDirectory": "/var/folders/h3/bfmnzb_j3zg3pdffgps1w3vh0000gn/T/jest",
  "clearMocks": false,
  "coveragePathIgnorePatterns": [
    "/node_modules/"
  ],
  "coverageReporters": [
    "json",
    "text",
    "lcov",
    "clover"
  ],
  "expand": false,
  "globals": {
    "__DEV__": true
  },
  "haste": {
    "defaultPlatform": "ios",
    "platforms": [
      "android",
      "ios",
      "native"
    ],
    "providesModuleNodeModules": [
      "react-native"
    ]
  },
  "moduleDirectories": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "moduleFileExtensions": [
    "js",
    "json",
    "jsx",
    "node"
  ],
  "moduleNameMapper": [
    [
      "^[./a-zA-Z0-9$_-]+\\.(bmp|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|psd|svg|webp)$",
      "RelativeImageStub"
    ],
    [
      "^React$",
      "/Users/erickim/Documents/Develop/react/glfm/node_modules/react"
    ]
  ],
  "modulePathIgnorePatterns": [
    "/Users/erickim/Documents/Develop/react/glfm/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/react-native/",
    "/Users/erickim/Documents/Develop/react/glfm/node_modules/react-native/packager/"
  ],
  "noStackTrace": false,
  "notify": false,
  "preset": "react-native",
  "resetMocks": false,
  "resetModules": false,
  "roots": [
    "/Users/erickim/Documents/Develop/react/glfm"
  ],
  "snapshotSerializers": [],
  "testEnvironment": "/Users/erickim/Documents/Develop/react/glfm/node_modules/jest-environment-node/build/index.js",
  "testMatch": [
    "**/__tests__/**/*.js?(x)",
    "**/?(*.)(spec|test).js?(x)"
  ],
  "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
    "/node_modules/"
  ],
  "testRegex": "",
  "testResultsProcessor": null,
  "testURL": "about:blank",
  "timers": "real",
  "transformIgnorePatterns": [
    "node_modules/(?!(jest-)?react-native|react-clone-referenced-element)"
  ],
  "useStderr": false,
  "verbose": null,
  "watch": false,
  "setupFiles": [
    "/Users/erickim/Documents/Develop/react/glfm/node_modules/babel-polyfill/lib/index.js",
    "/Users/erickim/Documents/Develop/react/glfm/node_modules/react-native/jest/setup.js"
  ],
  "transform": [
    [
      "^.+\\.js$",
      "/Users/erickim/Documents/Develop/react/glfm/node_modules/babel-jest/build/index.js"
    ]
  ],
  "rootDir": "/Users/erickim/Documents/Develop/react/glfm",
  "name": "005c8bf9b4d78dfa0bb0e32c0c55b0fb",
  "testRunner": "/Users/erickim/Documents/Develop/react/glfm/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/index.js",
  "cache": false,
  "watchman": true
}
```

Comment: It looks like your test script does not get transpiled to js. Try the methods in the following thread: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/770.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I figured it out. By default jest doesn't transform ES6 js code from `node_modules`. In my case, the package `react-navigation` module need to be translated. So I added `transformIgnorePatterns` to my jest configuration and everything worked:

```
{
  "preset": "react-native",
  "setupFiles": ["./test/setup.js"],
  "globals": {
    "__DEV__": true
  },
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest"
  },
  "transformIgnorePatterns": [
    "node_modules/(?!react-native|react-navigation)/"
  ]
}
```

https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/tutorial-react-native.html#transformignorepatterns-customization

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that node doesn't understand ES6 modules and JEST is node process, so using `import` inside your test throw this error. Instead of babel we specifically tell Webpack to transcompile ES6 modules.So, we can fix this error by telling babel that when we are in testing scenario please combile ES6 modules by using below babel configuration settings

```
 "env": {
    "test": {
        "plugins": ["transform-es2015-modules-commonjs"]
    }
}
```

you can download this babel plugin by npm

```
npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs
```

Hopefully this will fix your problem.